# Inject session objects into WebAPI controllers

Tags: asp.net, spring, spring-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I have a legacy webforms application

I've been given the task of migrating it to MCV but not throwing it all away.

I have to keep both applications running in the same project and migrate the functions gradually.

This app uses sessions strongly but I don't want coupling my WebApi to this session.

How can I inject this login context into my Controllers?

Could I have one spring context per session? how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True RESTful Web Api's should be stateless, meaning it should not keep track of any state initiated from the client like sessions for example. You can choose to still use MVC together with a RESTful Web API and then make use of expiring tokens between the API controller and MVC controller. This token needs to be passed back to the Web API on every call and is used to verify the authenticity of the current session.

Comment: Yeah!
This is what I'm talking about.
So, if I decide to make a Single Page App this token should be sent in all request since cookies aren't sent in ajax requests.
Is there a better way to keep it trasnparent, I mean, not passing it every time?

Comment: Do you think If I use mvc filters to set this loginInfo into my API Controller, I'm returning to session concepts?

Comment: It is possible to store the token in session memory on your Web API but then it becomes stateful. In REST, the correct way is to pass this along as an access token in every call, either in the header (my preference) or in the URI. This token can be used as a lookup for any other security tokens/sessions stored in memory for example